# ValueError: Can't handle mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput accuracy_score()

Tags: python, model, prediction

I am trying to determine the accuracy score of prediction models between KNN and Random Forest but the accuracy_score method is giving the error given in the subject line. My code is the following:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(x_train,y_train)
knn.predict(x_test)
#Accuracy of prediction
y_pred = knn.predict(x_test)
#predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

Output of the above accuracy print statement is :

```
Accuracy: 80.04%
```

Now the 2nd method:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, min_samples_leaf=10,     
random_state=1)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(model.score)
#Accuracy of prediction
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

The accuracy_score function gives the below error in the case of Random Forest

```
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-263-232dbb7449ea>", line 1, in <module>
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py",    
line 172, in accuracy_score
y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py",   
line 82, in _check_targets
"".format(type_true, type_pred))
ValueError: Can't handle mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous- 
multioutput
```

**Why is the accuracy_score in the case of 2nd classifier RandomForest giving this Value error?**
**ValueError: Can't handle mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput accuracy_score()**

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regression is for a continuous target variable. Classification is for a categorical target variable. You need to use RandomForestClassifier for a classification problem.

Comment: I have not used Regression if you read carefully two Classification techniques have been used ** KNN and RandomForest Classifier** The question is not which one to use the Question is ** Why is the accuracy_score in the case of 2nd classifier RandomForest giving this Value error? **

Comment: Your code says "from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor". This is regression. If you intended to do classification then you should have said "from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier".

Comment: You are right when I changed that to Classifier it works now so I accept your answer. @simon