# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and binary targets

Tags: python, logistic-regression

i get this error

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print ("Accuracy : ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and binary targets
```

i been changing the metrics im using logistic regression that using binary classification

Comment: does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724680/valueerror-cant-handle-mix-of-multilabel-indicator-and-continuous-multioutput?rq=1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check you y_pred to be of type int

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is quite descriptive enough. Are you sure `y_pred` is purely integer values because `accuracy_score` wont work on continuous values (float)